# Xamarin.Forms AppCenter Push when App in background or terminated

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I'm implementing app using Xamarin.Forms and target to Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS. I'm currently trying to add the Push function from AppCenter. I have followed the instruction at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms and added the below code in my App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts

        // This should come before AppCenter.Start() is called
        // Avoid duplicate event registration:
        if (!AppCenter.Configured)
        {
            Push.PushNotificationReceived += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Add the notification message and title to the message
                var summary = $"Push notification received:" +
                                    $"\n\tNotification title: {e.Title}" +
                                    $"\n\tMessage: {e.Message}";

                // If there is custom data associated with the notification,
                // print the entries
                if (e.CustomData != null)
                {
                    summary += "\n\tCustom data:\n";
                    foreach (var key in e.CustomData.Keys)
                    {
                        summary += $"\t\t{key} : {e.CustomData[key]}\n";
                    }
                }

                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(e.Title, e.Message, MobileLibrary.Resources.Localization.txtOK);

                // Send the notification summary to debug output
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(summary);
            };
        }

        AppCenter.Start("ios=XXX;android=XXX", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Push));
    }
```

Currently I'm testing on **Android**.

I have no problem to receive notification and get the message at `var summary` when the app is in foreground. My problem that I'm facing now is

1) When the app the in background, I get the notification. When I clicked on it, it will enter into the `PushNotificationReceived` event, but the `e.Title` and `e.Message` is empty.

> Answer: put the required data in the CustomData and it
>   will be maintained.

2) If I terminated the app, the notification will not appear at all.

Summary

1. When App is Foreground - Notification (NO); Message & Title (YES)
2. When App is Background - Notification (YES); Message & Title (NO)

> Answer: In Android, put in CustomData to keep the data required.

3. When App is Killed - Notification (NO); Message & Title (NO)

My question now is

1) What I did on Android (Java) is it that I need to implement Service and extend GcmListenerService. Is it that I need something similar for Xamarin.Forms/Xamarin.Android?

2) How about Xamarin.iOS? (I haven't started testing on it yet) What should I do over there?

Thank you.